# Undelete Identification questions made before the rule change

Tags: feature-request, moderation, identification-questions

I understand why ID questions asked within the past 3 years since the policy change are closed and removed, but why delete old questions, especially ones that have accepted answers? It can be very difficult to identify obscure songs, so why delete what could potentially be the only place on the internet with the answer?
Also, why is this policy only half-implemented, as there are some ID questions that are merely closed while others are deleted?

Comment: Do you have specific examples of old ID questions that got deleted?

Answer (score 1):

This process has been a long and slow due to the number of questions on the site. The mods have been doing batch of closing questions and for questions that have been closed a while deleted. The only factor that was talked about preserving is higher score questions which is a fraction of the total ID questions.

Deletion long term is preferred for may reasons . People coming here seeing an ID even if it's closed may not understand it's off topic and may ask more questions in the same vein. All the ID questions have tags that need to be removed and deleting them removes the tag. Editing is viable, but also bumps them which is not desireded. Blocking tags is also doable, but can also leave questions orphaned with no tags.

I will also point out deleted questions are not gone forever. Public accounts will not be able to see the posts, but the OP along with trusted members will be able to see them as long as they have the link to it.